# Export list to Word

Tags: export, word, word-automation

Is there a way to easily export a list to Microsoft Word 2010 from SharePoint 2010 via a button on the page? We'd like to have the data plugged into a Word template so the list values get formatted/placed correctly. We don't mind creating a custom web part if that's what it requires.

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy to create a control or a web part and place it on the page. The control would contain a button with code behind that uses [OpenXML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/) to generate the Word document.

I've done similar things and it's very easy. Just create a Word document using Word and format it as you like, then use the Document Reflector from the OpenXML SDK v2+ to generate a C# class that generates a document. Copy that class (and reference the OpenXML assemblies) and modify to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Wictor. You make it sound so easy. As a SharePoint newbie, a detailed article on this would be great :) Also, is it possible to make the button a part of the list actions?

Comment: Yea, you could attach it to the ribbon.

Comment: Thanks, Wictor. Can this 2007 article be used with 2010 to achieve what you talked about for the OpenXML SDK programming? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532473.aspx

Comment: Yes, it's a starter. Make sure you read what Eric White (http://ericwhite.com/blog/) has written in the past.

Comment: In addition to Wictor's answer, I would also recommend to use ClosedXml, a very convenient opensource project to work with OpenXML: http://closedxml.codeplex.com/